# Redshift with R

Tags: r, amazon-redshift, rpostgresql

I am new to connecting to Redshift via R, I have read other questions but am still getting an error when I attempt to create a table. 
I have successfully set up a connection and I thought set up the table successfully:

```
redshiftcon <- dbConnect(mm, user="username", password="secret_password",
                    dbname="dbtable", host="hostname", port="portnumber")


dbSendQuery(redshiftcon,
"create table ss_playground.test_table (unique_id VARCHAR,
category VARCHAR,
name VARCHAR,
number_min float);")

<PostgreSQLResult:(70214,5,1)>
```

However, when I attempt to check if the table exists and if the fields are there, I get the following message:

```
dbExistsTable(redshiftcon, ss_playground.test_table)

Error in is(object, Cl) : 
error in evaluating the argument 'name' in selecting a method for function
'dbExistsTable': Error: object 'ss_playground.test_table' not found

> dbExistsTable(redshiftcon, 'ss_playground.test_table')
[1] FALSE
```

I am confused because I thought the table was created successfully, but also cannot find it in the database itself.
When I attempt to send it and create it again, I get the following:

```
> dbSendQuery(redshiftcon,
         "create table ss_playground.test_table (unique_id VARCHAR,
category VARCHAR,
name VARCHAR,
number_min float);")

Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  Relation   
'test_table' already exists)
```

Is there something I am missing?

Please help! 
Thank you

Comment: I am not sure, but try adding `commit;` after you create table. It is possible that your changes are session specific and you might wanna commit them first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `ss_playground` is not the default schema for this user/role. You can have a go at setting the schema as default. Have a peek [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-OTHER).

To fix your code quickly you can try:

```
dbExistsTable(redshiftcon, c("ss_playground","test_table"))
```

or hack it up as

```
any(grepl("test_table",dbListTables(redshiftcon)))
```

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful! with this code, I see that in fact the table exists. `> dbExistsTable(redshiftcon, c("ss_playground","test_table"))
[1] TRUE` Will I need to follow up to grant permissions ?

Comment: Assuming your user ``username`` has access to schema, simply run ``SET search_path = ss_playground, public;``. So looks like  ``rs <- dbSendQuery(conn =redshiftcon, "SET search_path =ss_playground, public;")``. Then you don't need to do ``c(schema, tabl_name)`` and can get by just asking by ``dbExistsTable(redshiftcon, test_table)``.

Comment: I dont particularly want to make that entire schema public, is there a way to make only that particular table public instead? I was playing around with `> dbSendQuery(redshiftcon, "grant select on test_table in schema ss_playground to readonly;")` where readonly is another user

Comment: well its not making this public, its just saying each query should be first tries on schema ``ss_playground`` and then on ``public``. Have a go at reading through the redshift docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_search_path.html